# Remove p tags from within tables

Tags: php

How do you remove all `p` tags, from within all `tables` and cells only, and replace them with `br` tags please?

So this...

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1.</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>
                <p>
                Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem
                <a class="" style="" href="www.accusantiumdoloremque.co.uk">www.accusantiumdoloremque.co.uk</a>
                </p>
                <p>Laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore ve</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

...would become this...

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1.</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem
                <br />
                <a class="" style="" href="www.accusantiumdoloremque.co.uk">www.accusantiumdoloremque.co.uk</a>
                <br />
                <br />
                Laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore ve
                <br />
                    <br />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm guessing I would use something like this:

```
$mycontent = str_replace('<p>', '', $mycontent );
$mycontent = str_replace('</p>', '<br /><br />', $mycontent );
```

But how would I only use it on `tables` and table cells, not any other content?

Comment: 1) I feel this is the wrong approach, because it looks like you are looking to make style changes instead of markup. 2) Where is te data coming from? What happens when the `p` tags have attributes / different syntax?

Comment: I already have a regex in place to strip out all `style` attributes, and another for empty tags.

Comment: You realize your regex "solution" is going to fail right?

Comment: What makes you say that?

Comment: Because there are only a few people I have ever met who could pull it of

Comment: @PeeHaa No-one can pull it off, at best you get people who's solution fails under a smaller set of circumstances than other peoples. HTML is not a language that can be parsed with RegExps, and attempting to do so is a path to madness. This is a partial list of exceptions you'd have to consider: comments(`<!-- <table> --><p>`), javascript(`<script> // <table></script><p>`), CDATA(`<![CDATA[ <table> ]]> <p>`), textarea content(`<textarea><table></textarea><p>`) and quoted attributes(`<div data-foo="<table>"><p>`).

Comment: @scragar people already have pulled it off :) It depends on the regex flavor used but it is certainly possible.

Comment: @PeeHaa People can easily pull it off for very small specific situations, but parsing HTML with a single RegExp isn't possible, even the Perl HTML libraries that use the advanced perl regexps use multiple regexps to identify content to look at and trim to the content they require with excessive readaheads and backrefs. It's insanity to try and produce a single pattern that will work, and it's not going to be a sustainable solution. If you really need to do that sort of thing use a DOM parser and a xpath lookup or walk the tree, far easier and maintainable.

Comment: Hey no argument there about it being insane and about using a HTML parser. I never ever said anything otherwise. I'm just telling you people did what you said was impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Just use jQuery. Use a selector for all td or tr elements and you are done

Comment: It has to be in php as it's part of a bigger php script.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This. If there is more than one table you can put this code in a loop and use it.

    $contentarr= explode("</table>",$mycontent);
    $subcontent=$contentarr[0];
    $subcontentarr=explode("<table>",$subcontent);
    $data=$subcontentarr[1];
    $data=str_replace('<p>', '', $data );
    $data=str_replace('</p>', '<br /><br />', $data);
    $subcontentarr[1]=$data;
    $substr=implode("<table>",$subcontentarr);
    $contentarr[0]=$substr;
    $new_content=implode("</table>",$contentarr);
```